# Q&A migrated here from Open Science private beta is 404-ing

Tags: support, migration

Following the failed beta of Open Science, several Q&As were migrated to other suitable SE sites. One of my [Answers](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/licenses-for-open-science) was migrated to Open Source, but when visiting this Q&A I see a page not found 404.

Is there a problem with the migration or is this intentional? either way I'm just checking.

Comment: Yep, we tried to say not to migrate it but it came over anyway for some reason. We rejected it and then deleted it because it was way too broad for the site's quality standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing a 404 because the post is deleted.

We asked for that post specifically not to be migrated here because of some issues we found with the post (namely, that its scope was far too broad to be of use on this site). Nothing against your answer!

It got migrated here anyway, which is why you got the notification that your answer was migrated. I've since cleared the migration and deleted the post, so any content from it that you have links to will 404 for anyone under 2k rep.

Comment: Thanks; and no problem. I was sceptical that this would be useful here (very broad).